# weird behaviour when using $regexMatch with $expr on numbers (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb

Can someone explain me why ** sometimes ** this query returns empty result or very few results?

(I have hundreds of documents in my collection where the field `data.myIntId` is an integer containing 333)

```
db.test.find({
    $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
            input: { $toString: '$data.myIntId' },
            regex: '333',
            options: 'i',
        },
    }
})
```

Am I missing something?

PS: I want my customers to be able to search within IDs that are numbers. For another feature, I also want them to perform $gt/$lt queries (that's why it's not possible to just convert the field to a string).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found, $toString convert 3149085095 to "3.14909e+09" and not "3149085095" ‍♂️

Comment: No pal its not converting for me. I tried with  the same value. There might be something else.